# What would happen if I put an iPad sim card in my iPhone

Tags: iphone, cellular-data

Can I put a data only, no voice or text sim card in an iPhone.

I'm keen to get 4g but I've found the cheapest monthly plan for a nano sim is  **[£33 for 3GB](http://shop.ee.co.uk/ee-nano-sim/4gee-simo-33-30-days/pay-monthly/extras/)**. This included unlimited text(SMS) and unlimited voice calls.

I make almost no calls, and few text messages.

I was looking at what plans were available for the ipad mini (nano-sim too) and noticed it was half the price: **[£15.99 for 3GB](http://shop.ee.co.uk/ee-nano-sim/4gee-broadband-simo-15-99-30d/pay-monthly/extras/)**. Pretty big difference.

**Has anyone tried an iPad only sim in an iPhone?**

- I'd use iMessage, FaceTime & skype to get round the lack of voice and text, and keep my old iphone 4 as a backup with a PAYG sim.

Notes:

- iPad mini wifi - so I intend to tether
- iPhone 5s(when it arrives)
- new 4g networks are coming in December so I don't se the point in locking myself into a 12 month plan, when the price is likely to drop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called EE and the guy said I would be unable to make calls or send text messages.

I will try this out and see how I go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works with bell 5g a month for $35 . Running it for over a year.
Best plan ever! I can I message any iphone , got a BBM app. And a free VoIP phone app. Plus free txt apps are available ...